# Most Efficient Way to Convert a Complex List of Dictionaries Into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in `event_records` and a subset of the list is below.  Each dictionary contains 2 or 3 key-value pairs.  The first key is `item` and the corresponding value is `event#status`.

The second key is `count` and the corresponding value consists of a dictionary containing 8 key-value pairs + 1 key-value pair where the value is a list of 9 dictionaries each containing 3 key-value pairs.

The third key (only present some of the time) is `errors` and the corresponding value is a dictionary with 3 key-value pairs in a list.

What is the most efficient way to convert the below list of dictionaries in `event_records` into a pandas dataframe?  I tried the following code, but the speed and performance are very slow.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

df1 = json_normalize(event_records)
df2 = df1['customEvents']
custom_events_list = []
for element in df2: 
    df3 = json_normalize(element)
    df4 = df3[['type', 'value']]
    df5 = df4.T
    df5.columns = df5.iloc[0]
    df5 = df5[1:]
    custom_events_list.append(df5)
df6 = pd.concat(custom_events_list)
df6 = df6.reset_index(drop = True)
df7 = df1.join(df6)

df8 = df1['errors']
event_error_list = []
for element in df8: 
    df9 = json_normalize(element)
    df10 = df9[['response', 'feedback']]
    event_error_list.append(df10)
df11 = pd.concat(event_error_list)
df11 = df11.reset_index(drop = True)
df12 = df7.join(df11)
df13 = df12[['old_id', 'new_id', 'event_id', 'event_time', 'value', 'quantity', 'unique_id', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14', 'response', 'feedback']]
```

```
event_records = [{'item': 'event#status',
  'count': {'item': 'event#count',
   'old_id': '123',
   'new_id': '456',
   'event_id': '111',
   'event_time': '1200',
   'value': 1.0,
   'quantity': '1',
   'unique_id': '222',
   'customEvents': [{'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A3', 'value': ''},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A4', 'value': '11AA'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A6', 'value': 'AAB1'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A9', 'value': ''},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A10', 'value': '10.5'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A11', 'value': 'ABC'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A12', 'value': 'NYR'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A13', 'value': 'NYR'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A14', 'value': 'NYR'}]},
  'errors': [{'item': 'event#Error',
    'response': 'NONE',
    'feedback': 'Event not found'}]},
 {'item': 'event#status',
  'count': {'item': 'event#count',
   'old_id': '567',
   'new_id': '789',
   'event_id': '333',
   'event_time': '1400',
   'value': 1.0,
   'quantity': '1',
   'unique_id': '444',
   'customEvents': [{'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A3', 'value': ''},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A4', 'value': '22BB'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A6', 'value': 'CCD1'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A9', 'value': ''},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A10', 'value': '20.5'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A11', 'value': 'ABC'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A12', 'value': 'NYR'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A13', 'value': 'NYR'},
    {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A14', 'value': 'NYR'}]}}]
```

The desired Pandas dataframe output is as follows:

```
old_id    new_id    event_id    event_time    value    quantity    unique_id    A3    A4    A6    A9    A10    A11    A12    A13    A14    response    feedback
123       456       111         1200          1.0      1           222                11AA  AAB1        10.5   ABC    NYR    NYR    NYR    NONE        Event not found
567       789       333         1400          1.0      1           444                22BB  CCD1        20.5   ABC    NYR    NYR    NYR
```

Comment: kindly check ur event_records data, it does not seem to be properly formatted

Comment: Thanks.  I updated event_records and it is properly formatted now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to data-frames is a slow process because each addition recreates the entire object. In your code you create 13 data-frames. I recommend you do all of the formatting outside of the data-frame object, and then create the data-frame in one fell swoop. There are multiple ways to create a data-frame (see this [geeks for geeks page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/) for a few examples), and you could choose whichever is easiest for you

The way that seems the fastest to me would be to iterate through the event records list as follows:

```
processed_records = []
for event_record in event_records:
    processed_records.append(process_record(event_record))

df = pd.DataFrame(processed_records)
```

Then you need to write a function called "process_record") that extracts all the relevant data out of the event records and returns it in a dictionary format (e.g. `{"old_id": 123, "new_id": 345, "event_id": 567 ..."feedback": None}`). There are a few quirks you'll have to make sure to pay attention to. Because some records dont have errors, you need to make sure you add "None" or -1 or some other value to indicate a null value on this column. Otherwise you will get a "Nan" in your column in pandas. This will take a bit of tedious code, but it will be much faster than the version where you create 12 unnecessary data-frames.

EDIT: Clarified code

Answer (score 0):

The data processing here is quite elegant thanks to pandas json_normalize & list comprehension.

first extract the custom events

```
parent_fields = ['old_id', 'new_id', 'event_id', 'event_time', 'value', 'quantity', 'unique_id']
custom_events = json_normalize(
    [r['count'] for r in event_records], 
    'customEvents',
    parent_fields,
    record_prefix='#'
)
```

then extract the `errors`. Here I use a lesser known feature of list comprehensions that allow both filtering & iteration on nested elements to generate the records that are fed into the DataFrame constructor

```
errors = pd.DataFrame(
   [(e['response'], e['feedback'],r['count']['unique_id'])
    for r in event_records if 'errors' in r
    for e in r['errors']], 
   columns=['response', 'feedback', 'unique_id'])
```

merge the two dataframes

```
df = custom_events.merge(
    errors, 
    left_on='unique_id', 
    right_on='unique_id',
    how='left'
)
shaped = df.set_index(
    [c for c in df.columns if c != '#value']
).unstack('#type')
```

at this point, `shaped` is a dataframe with the desired shape, however the columns are still a multi-index instead of a flat list.

```
#shaped outputs:
                                                                                    #value
#type                                                                                  A10  A11  A12  A13  A14 A3    A4    A6 A9
old_id new_id event_id event_time value quantity unique_id response feedback
123    456    111      1200       1.0   1        222       NONE     Event not found   10.5  ABC  NYR  NYR  NYR     11AA  AAB1
567    789    333      1400       1.0   1        444       NaN      NaN               20.5  ABC  NYR  NYR  NYR     22BB  CCD1
```

set the columns to the 2nd level in the multi-index & reset the dataframe's index, *and if you want to you can re-order the columns*

```
shaped.columns = shaped.columns.levels[1]
shaped.reset_index()
# outputs:
#type old_id new_id event_id event_time  value quantity unique_id response         feedback   A10  A11  A12  A13  A14 A3    A4    A6 A9
0        123    456      111       1200    1.0        1       222     NONE  Event not found  10.5  ABC  NYR  NYR  NYR     11AA  AAB1
1        567    789      333       1400    1.0        1       444      NaN              NaN  20.5  ABC  NYR  NYR  NYR     22BB  CCD1
```

Answer (score 0):

i'll suggest we create the three dataframes and concatenate after. Also, some of the data is nested in lists, nested in dicts, and nested in lists. some journey. Personally, i use a library(jmespath) to make the journey easier, and IMHO, simpler. as i said, personally. here goes :

```
import jmespath
from collections import defaultdict
```

First we create the dataframe for the ids; the nesting isn't so deep here, a list comprehension(well a nested list comprehension) should do the trick, plus it is a more sensible approach here:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({key:value 
                    for key,value 
                    in entry['count'].items()
                    if key not in  ('customEvents','item')} 
                   for entry in event_records)

df1

  old_id    new_id  event_id    event_time  value   quantity    unique_id
0   123     456     111           1200       1.0       1         222
1   567     789     333           1400       1.0       1         444
```

Second dataframe to pull out is the 'As'; this is where [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) comes into play, as it allows easy traversal of nested lists/dicts. you could write a nested list comprehension here, but jmespath allows us avoid that nestedness :

the path to customEvents is : `list -> dict -> count -> customEvents -> list<br>`
keys are accessed in jmespath via the dot(.) symbol, while lists are accessed via the brackets([]) symbol

```
As =jmespath.compile('[].count.customEvents[]')
out = As.search(event_records)

print(out)

[{'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A3', 'value': ''},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A4', 'value': '11AA'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A6', 'value': 'AAB1'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A9', 'value': ''},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A10', 'value': '10.5'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A11', 'value': 'ABC'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A12', 'value': 'NYR'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A13', 'value': 'NYR'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A14', 'value': 'NYR'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A3', 'value': ''},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A4', 'value': '22BB'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A6', 'value': 'CCD1'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A9', 'value': ''},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A10', 'value': '20.5'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A11', 'value': 'ABC'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A12', 'value': 'NYR'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A13', 'value': 'NYR'},
 {'item': 'event#custom', 'type': 'A14', 'value': 'NYR'}]
```

next, we use the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) option to extract our type and value keys

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for i in out:
    d[i['type']].append(i['value'])

print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'A3': ['', ''],
             'A4': ['11AA', '22BB'],
             'A6': ['AAB1', 'CCD1'],
             'A9': ['', ''],
             'A10': ['10.5', '20.5'],
             'A11': ['ABC', 'ABC'],
             'A12': ['NYR', 'NYR'],
             'A13': ['NYR', 'NYR'],
             'A14': ['NYR', 'NYR']})
```

read it into a dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2

  A3     A4      A6     A9  A10     A11 A12 A13 A14
0       11AA    AAB1        10.5    ABC NYR NYR NYR
1       22BB    CCD1        20.5    ABC NYR NYR NYR
```

third part is to extract the errors data: 
same concept of `[]` for lists and `.` for keys apply here as well; however, we can get back our data in a `key:value` pair, like a dict:

```
errors = jmespath.compile('[].errors[].{response:response,feedback:feedback}')
err = errors.search(event_records)

print(err)

[{'response': 'NONE', 'feedback': 'Event not found'}]
```

read into a dataframe:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(err)
df3

    response    feedback
0   NONE    Event not found
```

and we are at the end - [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframes on the columns :

```
result = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis = 1)



   old_id  new_id   event_id    event_time  value   quantity    unique_id   A3  A4  A6  A9  A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 response    feedback
0   123     456      111         1200       1.0         1       222            11AA AAB1        10.5    ABC NYR NYR NYR NONE    Event not found
1   567     789     333         1400        1.0         1       444           22BB  CCD1        20.5    ABC NYR NYR NYR NaN NaN
```